Trouble installing mupdf with nix package manager
I am trying to use nix package manager which is supposed to be a better than apt. As an example I tried to delete mupdf, my pdf file viewer using sudo apt-get remove --purge mupdf and install it with nix with the command
$ nix-env -iA nixpkgs.mupdf
installing 'mupdf-1.23.6'

I then tried to use it with the command mupdf apdffile.pdf but got the folllowing error
GLUT error:  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow
X Error of failed request:  167
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 ()
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21
  Serial number of failed request:  50
  Current serial number in output stream:  50

What am I doing wrong?
